# Не работает авторизация "php_verify"

Tags: php, авторизация

Помогите найти ошибку в коде. Есть регистрация, успешно вносит хэш пароля в базу:

```
<?php
  namespace xcode;
  class registerUser {
  private $conn;
  private $escapeObj;
  private $id;

  private $name;
  private $usename;
  private $email;
  private $password;
  private $gender;
  private $birthday = '';
  private $location = '';
  private $hometown = '';
  private $about = '';

  private $allowedGenders = array('male', 'female');

function __construct()
{
    global $conn;
    $this->conn = $conn;
    $this->escapeObj = new \xcode\Escape();
    return $this;
}

public function setConnection(\mysqli $conn)
{
    $this->conn = $conn;
    return $this;
}

protected function getConnection()
{
    return $this->conn;
}

public function register()
{
    if (! empty ($this->name) && 
        ! empty ($this->username) && 
        ! empty ($this->email) && 
        ! empty ($this->password) && 
        ! empty ($this->gender))
    {
        $query = $this->getConnection()->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_ACCOUNTS . " (active,about,cover_id,email,email_verification_key,name,password,time,type,username) VALUES (1,'" . $this->about . "',0,'" . $this->email . "','" . md5(generateKey()) . "','" . $this->name . "','" . $this->password . "'," . time() . ",'user','" . $this->username . "')");

        if ($query)
        {
            $this->id = $this->getConnection()->insert_id;
            $query2 = $this->getConnection()->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_USERS . " (id,birthday,gender,current_city,hometown) VALUES (" . $this->id . ",'" . $this->birthday . "','" . $this->gender . "','" . $this->location . "','" . $this->hometown . "')");

            if ($query2)
            {
                $timelineObj = new \xcode\User();
                $timelineObj->setId($this->id);
                $get = $timelineObj->getRows();
                return $get;
            }
        }
    }
}

private function validateUsername($u)
{
    if (strlen($u) > 3 && ! is_numeric($u) && preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/', $u))
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public function setName($n)
{
    if (! empty($n))
    {
        $this->name = $this->escapeObj->stringEscape($n);
    }
}

public function setUsername($u)
{
    if ($this->validateUsername($u))
    {
        $this->username = $this->escapeObj->stringEscape($u);
    }
}

public function setEmail($e)
{
    if (filter_var($e, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $this->email = $this->escapeObj->stringEscape($e);
    }
}

public function setPassword($p)
{
    if (! empty($p))
    {
        $hashpass = password_hash('$p', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $this->password = $hashpass;
    }
}

public function setGender($g)
{
    if (in_array($g, $this->allowedGenders))
    {
        $this->gender = $g;
    }
}

public function setBirthday($b)
{
    if (is_array($b))
    {
        $b = implode('-', $b);
        $regex = '/^([0-9]{1,2})\-([0-9]{1,2})\-([0-9]{4})$/';

        if (preg_match($regex, $b))
        {
            $this->birthday = $b;
        }
    }
}

public function setLocation($l)
{
    if (! empty($l))
    {
        $this->location = $this->escapeObj->stringEscape($l);
    }
}

public function setHometown($h)
{
    if (! empty($h))
    {
        $this->hometown = $this->escapeObj->stringEscape($h);
    }
}

public function setAbout($a)
{
    if (! empty($a))
    {
        $this->about = $this->escapeObj->stringEscape($a);
    }
}
}
```

А есть авторизация, она не проходит, пишет пароль неверный. Чую что ошибка именно в коде, не могу понять где, ломаю несколько дней голову, раньше не заморачивался с паролями, теперь вынужден.

Вот код для входа в профиль:

```
<?php
$data['error_message'] = $lang['error_empty_login'];

$loginId = $escapeObj->stringEscape($_POST['login_id']);
$hash = password_hash($_POST['login_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$cr_pass = password_verify($_POST['login_password'], $hash);

$userId = getUserId($conn, $loginId);

if ($userId)
{
$query = $conn->query("SELECT id,username,email_verified FROM " . DB_ACCOUNTS . " WHERE id=$userId AND password='$cr_pass' AND type='user' AND active=1");
$data['error_message'] = $lang['error_bad_login'];

if ($query->num_rows == 1)
{
    $fetch = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $continue = true;

    if ($config['email_verification'] == 1 && $fetch['email_verified'] == 0)
    {
        $continue = false;
        $data['error_message'] = $lang['error_verify_email'];
    }

    if ($continue == true)
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $fetch['id'];
        $_SESSION['user_pass'] = $cr_pass;

        if (isset($_POST['keep_logged_in']) && $_POST['keep_logged_in'] == true)
        {
            setcookie('sk_u_i', $_SESSION['user_id'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
            setcookie('sk_u_p', $_SESSION['user_pass'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
        }

        $data['status'] = 200;
        $data['redirect_url'] = smoothLink('index.php?tab1=home');
    }
}
else
{
  $data['error_message'] = $lang['incorrect_password'];
}
}
else
{
  $data['error_message'] = $lang['no_user_found'];
}
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($data);
$conn->close();
exit();
```

Буду ОЧЕНЬ БЛАГОДАРЕН.

Answer (score 2):

С программированием, так понимаю, раньше тоже не сталкивались?

Как это делается:

1. На этапе разработки выставьте `display_errors = On`,
   `display_startup_errors = On` и `error_reporting = E_ALL` (или -1, если пользуетесь музейными версиями PHP) в `php.ini` и исправьте все
   встреченные предупреждения языка.
2. Не помогло. Разбираемся с логикой. Что там? Пароль неверный? При каком условии выдаётся сообщение, что пароль неверный? Наверное, это `incorrect_password`. Насколько видно по вашему скверно отформатированному коду, случается это при `$query->num_rows != 1`
3. почему запрос может вернуть не одну строку? Например, может вернуть две строки.
   Выведите текст запроса на экран, посмотрите, так ли он выглядит как должен. Затем вставьте этот запрос в клиент mysql и выполните его. Разберитесь, из-за какого условия запрос возвращает не 1 строку.
4. долго ли, коротко ли, но всё-таки заметили, что в запросе указано `password='1'`. Оп, а почему это? `$cr_pass` равен результату `password_verify`. Смотрим в [мануал](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Ну да, функция возвращает `boolean`. Вряд ли в базе поле `password` булево.

И что же неправильно?
`password_hash` для входа не нужен. Он используется только записи хеша пароля в базу.
Для проверки пароля вам нужно по логину достать хэш пароля из базы и передать его в `password_verify`.

В вашем варианте

```
$hash = password_hash($_POST['login_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$cr_pass = password_verify($_POST['login_password'], $hash);
```

`$cr_pass` будет всегда true.